# Android : Layout Weight not working in grid layout

Tags: android

In the image, I want the buttons to have equal width. I have set the column weight and row weight to 1 but still, it does not seem to work.

[image]

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.agraw.basicphrases.MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:onClick="clickFunction"
        android:text="Do You Speak English?"
        android:tag="doyouspeakenglish"/>
</GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Remove `android:gravity="fill"` line from XML and Check. As per [GridLayout Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html), Define either `Gravity` or `weight`. And supports weight in 21 or higher version.

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution (y).

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Button tag like this

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:onClick="clickFunction"
        android:text="Do You Speak English?"
        android:tag="doyouspeakenglish"/>
```